# Deselect all selected values from multiselect by clicking link after toggle

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link that when clicked, a multiselect appears and if you click it again, the dropdown fades out. If the user selects values though and then clicks to remove the sizes, I want everything to be deselected without the user having to manually go deselect each item.

```
<a href="" id="add_colour">Add colour</a>  
<a href="" id="add_size">Add size</a>

<div class="form-group" id="size">
   <select multiple data-title="Select sizes" multiple name="size[]" class="selectpicker size" data-style="btn-block">
      <option value="xs">x-small</option>
      <option value="s">small</option>
      <option value="m">Medium</option>
      <option value="l">large</option>
      <option value="xl">x-larg</option>
      <option value="2xl">xx-large</option>
   </select>
</div>


$("#add_size").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    if ($("#size").is(":visible")) {
        $(".size option:selected").prop("selected", false);
        $("#size").fadeOut();
        $(this).html("Add Sizes");

    } else {
        $("#size").fadeIn();
        $(this).html("Remove size");
    }
});
```

This does not work but does not produce any errors in console either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the value rto default and refresh the select like :

```
$("#add_size").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($("#size").is(":visible")) 
  {
    //Set the value to default
    $(".size").val('default_value');

    //Refresh the selectpicker
    $(".size").selectpicker("refresh");


    $("#size").fadeOut();
    $(this).html("Add Sizes");

  } else {
    $("#size").fadeIn();
    $(this).html("Remove size");
  }
});
```

**NOTE :** If there's no "defaul_value" you could leave it empty like :

```
$(".size").val('').selectpicker("refresh");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can give all these select a certain class, and then use it to get all these selects you want, and set their values to 0

example

```
$(".selectClass").each(function() {
  $( this ).val("");
  // if this didn't work, usually it does
  $(this).removeProp("selected");

});
```